# Delete duplicated elements in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I thought that in Python such a syntax:

```
b=12
a=b
```

made 'a' and 'b' exactly the same element. In fact:

```
id(b)
>>>31223540  
id(a)
>>>31223540
a is b
>>>True
```

But if I tell the interpreter to delete 'a', 'b' stays at its place.

```
del a
b
>>>12
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you cannot delete the number `12` from python.  It's deleting the reference to `12` (`a`).  But the actual object of `12` still exists and `b` is still referenced to it

**EDIT** I want to be clear about something.  The syntax

```
b=12
a=b
```

does NOT make `a` and `b` the exact same element.  It makes them refer to the same element

Answer (score 0):

At python, a variable is actually a pointer.
Therefor, a is pointing to 12, as well as b.
When you request the id, by using the id() function, you get the id that a and b are pointing to, which is 12. The fact that a variable is actually a pointer, is encapsulated from the user at most cases, but this is not one of them.